# How do i change bootstrap columns when resizing screen?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to change one of my columns `number` when resizing screen to `md` (width 1024px).

Something like this:

`[.col-md-2][.col-md-8][.col-md-2]` becomes `[hidden][.col-md-12][hidden]`

My current code:

```
  <div class="col-md-2 hidden-md"></div>
  <div class="col-md-8"></div>
  <div class="col-md-2 hidden-md"></div>
```

How do i change `<div class="col-md-8"></div>` to `<div class="col-md-12"></div>` on resize?

Comment: Why? `media query` is my suggestion.

Comment: Im trying to avoid custom @media queries, because i think this can be achieved by just using bootstrap classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer for this after some time, its really simple and doesn't require any custom @media css or any custom css code whatsoever. Hers the html:

`<div class="col-xs-0 col-sm-0 col-md-0 col-lg-2"></div>
 <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-8"></div>
 <div class="col-xs-0 col-sm-0 col-md-0 col-lg-2"></div>`

1st and 3rd column become 'invisible' on 'md' size and 2nd column become full size (12)

Answer (score 0):

Try following code. this will expand the middle column on small screen devices.

```
<div class="col-md-2 hidden-sm"></div>
<div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12"></div>
<div class="col-md-2 hidden-sm"></div>
```

but make sure your bootstrap must be customized and `@screen-sm` must start from `1024` for this

If not then you will need to add custom css for 1024 resolution using media queries

```
col-md-8 { 
    width: 100%;
}
col-md-2 {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this: **[Updated Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/8076/)**

```
 <div class="col-lg-2 hidden-md"></div>
 <div class="col-sm-12"></div>
 <div class="col-lg-2 hidden-md"></div>
```

For **[Reference 1](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities)** **[reference 2](http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/bootstrap-grid-system.php)**

Comment: This wont hide first and last divs on MD size, and it wont make middle div size 12 on MD size.

Comment: updated my answer, Then in your question you have to mention for col-lg only not in col-md

Answer (score 0):

Try to use @media as follows :

```
@media screen and (min-width:1024px){
  .hidden-md{
     display:none;
}
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Im trying to avoid using custom @media, i think it can be done by just using bootstrap classes.